# 1 Corinthians 12:12-31 - Should Unpresentable Parts be Honoured Too?

Tags: 1-corinthians

Further to [my previous question about 1 Corinthians 12:12-31](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/28466), is 1 Corinthians 12:12-31 telling us that we should not place greater honour on certain parts of the body than others?

If so, should we be treating our "unpresentable parts" in the same way as those which **are** presentable?  After-all, "If one part suffers, every other part suffers with it." - 1 Corinthians 12:26 (NIV)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I'm missing something in your question but yes, each part of the body is treated the same by God so (as verse 25 states) that there by no schism in the body.

In God's design, the less comely parts have more abundant honor so there is a balance in the body. The comely parts have an inherent honor due to their nature, that's why the scripture says in verse 24 that they have no need. God then bestows more honor to those uncomely as they are very necessary for the body to function properly and that there is a unity within the body as each part functions as designed by God.

> 22 Nay, much more those members of the body which seem to be more
>   feeble are necessary. 23 And those members of the body which we think
>   to be less honorable, upon these we bestow more abundant honor; and
>   our uncomely parts have more abundant comeliness. 24 For our comely
>   parts have no need, but God hath tempered the body together, having
>   given more abundant honor to that part which lacked, 25 that there
>   should be no schism in the body, but that the members should have the
>   same care one for another. (KJV)